# Connect to a external DB2 with ZendServer

Tags: php, db2, zend-server

I have been fighting with Zend Server 2018 while trying to connect to a remote AS/400 DB2.

I am using the IBM_DB2 php functions to do the connection but every time I get

```
[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1031N The database directory cannot be found on the indicated file system. SQLSTATE=58031 SQLCODE=-1031
```

Anyone else successful connecting the two?

What I've read online is that I need to catalog the servers.
So I have db2 running on an iseries at say 192.168.50.1 with a name of X232321 and a Windows 10 box running zend server 2018.
What commands would I need to catalog the two servers so I can use the db2 connector?  And what does that actually do?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this on the windows db2 client:

```
db2 "catalog tcpip node MY_IS remote 192.168.50.1 server 446"
db2 "catalog db MY_ALIAS at node MY_IS"
db2 "catalog dcs db MY_ALIAS as X232321"
```

You can set MY_IS, MY_ALIAS as you want (no more than 8 letters).
Port 446 may be different for your iSeries host.

Comment: In my php code that was on the iSeries I connect to the database with X232321 for the database name and then call out the specific tablename.column in the queries.  With your above example does any of that change?

Comment: I registered your iSeries database as MY_ALIAS. If you want to have this alias equal to your database name, then just amend MY_ALIAS to X232321 above in both commands.